# How to split this array into separated variables?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, split

I'm receiving this response from a server when I put print_r($response):

```
    {"success":true,"title_response":"SUCCESS","text_response":"any text"}}
```

I have tried use:

```
     list($var1, $var2,$var3)=explode(",", $response);
```

but result is:

```
     $var1= {"success":true;
     $var2= "title_response":"SUCCESS";
     $var3= text_response":"any text"}};
```

I need the result:

```
    $var1= true;
    $var2= "SUCCESS";
    $var3= "any text";
```

Any idea?

Comment: not really an answer but this should help        http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: It's a json_encoded string (mostly. There's an extra brace, could be a pasting issue?). Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the data out.

Comment: @aynber It is NOT a valid json_encoded string.  The `{ }` are unbalanced.  (Unless that is an typo in the question post.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a JSON string, you can use a combination of `json_decode` to convert to an object and then `get_object_vars` to get the object's variables as an array:

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = get_object_vars(json_decode($response));

echo $var2;   // SUCCESS
```

As noted in the comments, this will only work *if* the string is valid JSON.  I'm assuming a copy/paste error when writing the question, and that you do have valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i received this error:
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\elyo\date.php on line 179

Comment: @HernánDavidGómezS `date.php`? I don't see how that's related to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it as follows:

```
// Problem data (with unbalanced { }'s)
$response = '{"success":true,"title_response":"SUCCESS","text_response":"any text"}}';

// Remove trailing '}}'
$response = substr($response, 0, -2);

// Split on the commas
$temp = explode(',', $response);

// For each element in the array, split on the colon, and take second part
array_walk($temp, function(&$value) {
  $value = explode(":", $value)[1];
});

// Distribute array into your variables
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = $temp;
```

But this is ***very*** fragile code.  If your strings have commas or colons in it, it will break in various fashions.

It is better to get a valid JSON response, and parse it using the proper JSON functions, as explained by @Madbreaks.